# Do DuckDuckGo 'Lite' and 'HTML' search use query strings?

Tags: duckduckgo, querystring

[HTML](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html) and [Lite](https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/) are more lightweight variants of the standard DuckDuckGo search. There's no query string when searching, unlike on the main search page:

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sample+search+term&ia=web
```

As a result I can't add neither [as a search engine in Firefox Fenix](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/manage-my-default-search-engines-firefox-android) (mobile) or use [the keyword search feature](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Smart%20keywords) (desktop), for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a functional query string for each:

```
https://lite.duckduckgo.com/lite/?q=%s
https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=%s
```

`%s` refers to the search term, a placeholder.